# LINQ equivalent of my SQL Query for UNION ALL

Tags: sql-server, linq, sql-order-by, union, equivalent

```
(SELECT * FROM SheetHay WHERE SheetStatus = 2)
 UNION ALL(SELECT * FROM SheetHay WHERE SheetStatus = 1)
 UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM SheetHay WHERE SheetStatus  = 0)
 UNION ALL(SELECT * FROM SheetHay WHERE SheetStatus= 3)
```

I get result set like this:
[image]

I mean I get all '2' together, '0' together, '3' together ( no '1' in 
table yet). But when I use LINQ and UNION them I see the result on my grid in order of SheetID, the primary key. I mean I see the order of sheets displayed as 15,23,25,27,28,29 etc. But I want it just as the SQL result set.23,43,25,28 etc

```
IEnumerable<SheetHay> listTwos = Get(LINQ QUERY TO GET just twos);    
IEnumerable<SheetHay> listOnes = Get(LINQ QUERY TO GET just Ones);
IEnumerable<SheetHay> listZeros = Get(LINQ QUERY TO GET just  Zeros);
IEnumerable<SheetHay> listThrees = Get(LINQ QUERY TO GET just Threes);
....
    return listTwos.Union(listZeros).Union(listOnes).Union(listThrees);
```

Let me know if you need any other information. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use SQL like `SELECT * FROM SheetHay WHERE SheetStatus IN(0,1,2,3)) ORDER BY SheetStatus `?

Comment: Tim's comment in LINQ might look like `repo.Where(s => new [] {0, 1, 2, 3}.Contains(s.SheetStatus));`

Comment: @TimSchmelter. Because I will get the result set like all 0's first , then all 1's second, all 2's third and all 3's last. But I want all 2's first, 0's next, 1's third and finally 3's.

Comment: and if the order is important: `ORDER BY CASE SheetStatus WHEN '2' THEN 1 WHEN 1 THEN 2 WHEN 0 THEN 3 WHEN 3 THEN 4 END ASC, SheetStatus`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter. I need the LINQ equivalent statement. I will have to pull it up using LINQ on my code-behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use multiple queries you can use `CASE` in the `ORDER BY` in sql and a similar way in LINQ.

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM SheetHay 
WHERE SheetStatus IN(0,1,2,3)) 
ORDER BY CASE SheetStatus 
    WHEN 2 THEN 1 
    WHEN 1 THEN 2 
    WHEN 0 THEN 3 
    WHEN 3 THEN 4 END ASC, SheetStatus ASC
```

LINQ:

```
int[] status =  {0, 1, 2, 3};
var query = db.SheetHay 
    .Where(s => status.Contains(s.SheetStatus))
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.SheetStatus == 2)
    .ThenByDescending(s =>  s.SheetStatus == 1)
    .ThenByDescending(s =>  s.SheetStatus == 0)
    .ThenByDescending(s =>  s.SheetStatus == 3)
    .ThenBy(s =>  s.SheetStatus);
```

Descending because a comparison returns `bool` and `true` is "higher" than `false`(1/0).

You could also use a conditional operator to return an `int` for the ordering:

```
var query = db.SheetHay 
    .Where(s => status.Contains(s.SheetStatus))
    .OrderBy(s => s.SheetStatus == 2 ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(s =>  s.SheetStatus == 1 ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(s =>  s.SheetStatus == 0 ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(s =>  s.SheetStatus == 3 ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(s =>  s.SheetStatus);
```

Comment: This looks like a good general purpose solution.  I was interested to know what the query plan would look like so I used LinqPad to run a similar query against one of my DBs and I noticed that it spent about 20% of its time performing index seeks and about 80% of its time sorting the results.  If 0, 1, 2, 3 are the only values for SheetStatus then this query will likely devolve into a table scan.  My proposed solution spent 99% of its time performing an index scan but the concatenation resulted in more reads which ultimately made my query take about 30% longer than Tims.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter. Thanks.. Worked like a charm. I went with the first approach... will try out the second one as well and thanks for the edited SQL query..always learning something new here..

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
IEnumerable<SheetHay> sheetHays =
    SheetHays
    .Where(x => x.SheetStatus < 3)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.SheetStatus)
    .Concat(SheetsHays.Where(x => x.SheetStatus == 3));
```

This is based on order 2, 1, 0, 3 (which is what you example query demonstrates).  This will need to be modified if you want order 2, 0, 1, 3 (which is what you sample code implies).